# What happened to B'Elanna Torres' holographic baby?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, holodeck

In the two-episode Voyager arc *The Killing Game*, B'Elanna Torres plays the role of Brigette, a French Resistance fighter who was impregnated by a holographic Nazi officer. Once the crew regains their identities in *The Killing Game, Part II*, B'Elanna is still evidently pregnant and even comments that she feels heavier and that the "baby" is kicking. I don't believe she is seen in this episode after leaving the holodeck.

What was going on here? Was the holodeck projecting a simulated baby into B'Elanna's womb? What happens when it... stops projecting?

Comment: I have not found an official statement, but most of the commentary on the episode is suggesting that the pregnancy was a holographic "prosthetic" much like the "baby bump" vests they have expectant fathers wear rather than anything internal.

Comment: If someone had never seen Voyager and wondered what it was like, I feel like the title of this question conveys a fairly accurate summary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### There's no need to simulate a fetus to simulate a pregnancy.

There's no specific evidence forthcoming in the episode itself, but there's also no reason to believe there was a "simulated baby", that there was anything "in her womb". It is within the capabilities of Star Trek's technology to create a **simulated pregnancy**. While many holodeck excursions involve pre-replicated clothing put on before entering the holodeck, holodecks can simulate clothes (as seen in *Star Trek: First Contact*'s "Perhaps something in satin?" bit). Doing so accurately would require modeling of weight and texture, so modelling the weight and shape of a holographic pregnancy bump and the included kicking is not much of a stretch.